# (English Grammar ) reason why my answer is wrong why it is not has been visiting , why is answer is have been visited

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Actual question :

> Since 2011 they _____ their son every year. (to visit) ?

My answer  :

> Since 2011 they has been visting their son every year

Correct is:

> Since 2011 they have visited their son every year.

why my answer is wrong ?

Comment: Hi, Shubham. I voted to close this question not because of the lack of research but because it appears to be a very elementary question more suitable for our sibling [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site. Beyond that mismatch, I would have voted to close the question because it is presented as being about a specific test question instead of about any larger issue of grammar or usage that might be of enduring interest to future EL&U readers. Such long-term value is an often overlooked criterion for question acceptability at this site.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer would be correct if you had used "**have** been visiting" even though, the answer suggests "have visited". If it were the former, it would be "have been visiting" not "has been visiting" as a plural subject "they", takes a plural verb.

Answer (score 1):

They' is plural. In english, you have to use 'have' for plural.
The dogs have finished their food. 
The children have packed up their toys.
The dog has finished its food.
The child has packed up his/her toy.